# Como faço para mostrar um <select> ao selecionar um <option> no form?

Tags: javascript, html

O código é assim:

```
<form name="frm1" action="#" method="post"> 

<option id="pacote1" class="form-control">Pacote</option> 
<option id="pacote2" class="form-control">Pacote 2</option> 

<select name="pacote" class="form-control">
<option value="1">Pacote Primario</option>"
```

Eu gostaria de inserir algo no `option`, onde eu selecionando o `option` de `id="pacote1"`, vai chamar o `select` `"pacote"` para o formulário, e se eu selecionar o `2`, chamará o novo select2 com o conteúdo para o formulário.

Comment: São dois `<select>`, sendo que o segundo depende do primeiro?

Comment: Isso, o <select> depende do primeiro <option>, porem ele tem que ficar fora do form, so pode aparecer ao ser selecionado por causa da função dentro do php

Comment: @cmte-cardeal você removeu a tag PHP da pergunta, mas manteve a Java? Não entendi.

Comment: <option id="pacote1" class="form-control">Pacote</option> 
<option id="pacote2" class="form-control">Pacote 2</option> 

mas prq você tá usando isso dessa forma? Sua pergunta tá meio confusa..

Answer (score 2):

não sei se te atende perfeitamente, mas espero que te ajude no desenvolvimento da solução. Abração.

```js
document.getElementById('pacotes').addEventListener('change', function(){

    var pacote = this.options[this.options.selectedIndex].value;
    preencheForm('frm1', parseInt(pacote));
});

function preencheForm(form, pacote){

    switch (pacote) {
        case 0:
        document.getElementsByName(form)[0].innerHTML = 
        `Selecione um pacote acima para começar...`
        ;
        break;
        case 1:
        document.getElementsByName(form)[0].innerHTML = 
        `
        <label for="pacote">Opções do Pacote</label>
        <select name="pacote" id="pacote" class="form-control">
            <option value="1">Pacote Primario</option>
        </select>
        <input type="submit" value="Enviar">
        `
        ;
        break;
        // coloque as outras opções aqui...
        default:
        document.getElementsByName(form)[0].innerHTML = 
        `Este pacote não possui opções, escolha outro...`
        ;
    }
}
```

```css
label {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<label for="pacotes">Pacotes</label>
<select id="pacotes">
    <option value="0">-- selecione --</option> 
    <option value="1">Pacote 1</option> 
    <option value="2">Pacote 2</option>
</select>
<form name="frm1" action="#" method="post">  
    Selecione um pacote acima para começar...
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Usando Jquery**

```js
var options = $("#d2").html();
$("#d1").change(function(e) {
    var selectedValue = $("#d1 :selected").val();
    $("#d2").html(options);
    $('#d2 :not([value="'+selectedValue+'"])').remove();
}).trigger('change');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-12">
<select name="d1" id="d1" tabindex="4" class="form-control toHide">
  <option value="">Selecione</option>
  <option value="1">Pacote</option>
  <option value="2">Pacote 2</option>
</select>
<select name="d2" id="d2" tabindex="5" class="form-control toHide">
  <option value="">Selecione</option>
  <option value="1">Pacote Primário</option>
  <option value="2">Pacote Secundário</option>
</select>
</div>
```

Comment: Funciontou! Obrigado.